# Effects of passing headers in a requests?

Tags: image, python-2.7, web-scraping, request

I want to know what difference it makes when you pass headers in `requests.get` i.e. the difference between `requests.get(url, headers)`  and `requests.get(url)`.

I have these two pieces of code:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests
import re

url = "http://www.amazon.in/SanDisk-micro-USB-connector-OTG-enabled-Android/dp/B00RBGYGMO"

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
XPATH_IMAGE_SOURCE = '//*[@id="main-image-container"]//img/@src'
image_source = tree.xpath(XPATH_IMAGE_SOURCE)
print 'type: ',type(image_source[0])
print image_source[0]
```

this whose out put is a url as you'd expect. But this:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests
import re

url = "http://www.amazon.in/SanDisk-micro-USB-connector-OTG-enabled-Android/dp/B00RBGYGMO"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
XPATH_IMAGE_SOURCE = '//*[@id="main-image-container"]//img/@src'
image_source = tree.xpath(XPATH_IMAGE_SOURCE)
print 'type: ',type(image_source[0])
print image_source[0]
```

has an output that starts with `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoIC`
I'm guessing this is the actual image without the rendering, just plain data. Any idea how I could keep it in url form? In what other ways does the presence of a header affect the response we get?

Thank You

Comment: Ok, so I asked around and googled around and found out that when I send the name of a browser in the header the server thinks that a browser sent a data. Knowing that a browser has the capability to render an image it send the image, but in case of no headers the server does not know If my device has the capacity to render the image, so it send me a url.

Comment: I also read that websites are less likely to block me with headers, that true?

Comment: I haven't found a solid source of documentation for this though!, can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Save the first code's response to html file and open in your browser:
[image]

as you can see, you are banned by amazon without headers.

use this xpath:

```
XPATH_IMAGE_SOURCE = '//*[@id="main-image-container"]//img/@data-old-hires'
```

out:

```
type:  <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/617TjMIouyL._SL1274_.jpg
```

this is raw html data:

```
<img alt=".." src="&#10;data:image/webp;base64,UklGRuYIAABXRUJQVlA4INoIAACQQQCdASosAcsAPrFWpEqkIqQhIxN6gIgWCek6r4bUf/..." 
data-old-hires="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/617TjMIouyL._SL1274_.jpg"
```

the picture url is in `data-old-hires` attribute.

Comment: Nope, at my end I'm getting the page. And scrapping the page for data. I guess its due to some difference in source of request?!

Comment: @Achyut Rastogi I post new XPath for you